# MongoDB: calculate average value for the document & then do the same thing across entire collection

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have collection of documents (Offers) with subdocuments (Salary) like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("zzz"),
    sphere: ObjectId("xxx"),
    region: ObjectId("yyy"),
    salary: {
        start: 10000,
        end: 50000
    }
}
```

And I want to calculate average salary across some region & sphere for the entire collection. I created query for this, it works, but it takes care only about salary start value.

```
db.offer.aggregate(
    [
        {$match:
            {$and: [
                {"salary.start": {$gt: 0}},
                {region: ObjectId("xxx")},
                {sphere: ObjectId("yyy")}
            ]}
        },
        {$group: {_id: null, avg: {$avg: "$salary.start"}}}
    ]
)
```

But firstly I want to calculate avarage salary (start & end) of the offer. How can I do this?

**Update.**

If value for "salary.end" may be missing in your data, you need to add one additional "$project" iteration to replace missing "salary.end" with existing "salary.start". Otherwise, the result of the average function will be calculated wrong due to ignoring documents with the lack of "salary.end" values.

```
db.offer.aggregate([
        {$match:
            {$and: [
                {"salary.start": {$gt: 0}},
                {"region": ObjectId("xxx")},
                {"sphere": ObjectId("yyy")}
            ]}
        },
        {$project:{"_id":1,
                   "sphere":1,
                   "region":1,
                   "salary.start":1,
                   "salary.end":1,
                   "salary.end": {$ifNull: ["$salary.end", "$salary.start"]}
                  }
        },
        {$project:{"_id":1,
                   "sphere":1,
                   "region":1,
                   "avg_salary":{$divide:[
                                          {$add:["$salary.start","$salary.end"]}
                                           ,2
                                          ]}}},
        {$group:{"_id":{"sphere":"$sphere","region":"$region"},
                 "avg":{$avg:"$avg_salary"}}}
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you aggregate has to be modified:

- `Match` the required region,sphere and where salary > 0.
- `Project` a extra field for each offer, which holds the average of
  start and end.
- Now `group` together the records with the same region and sphere, and
  apply the `$avg` aggregation operator on the `avg_salary` for each offer
  in that group,to get the average salary.

The Code:

```
db.offer.aggregate([
        {$match:
            {$and: [
                {"salary.start": {$gt: 0}},
                {"region": ObjectId("xxx")},
                {"sphere": ObjectId("yyy")}
            ]}
        },
        {$project:{"_id":1,
                   "sphere":1,
                   "region":1,
                   "avg_salary":{$divide:[
                                          {$add:["$salary.start","$salary.end"]}
                                           ,2
                                          ]}}},
        {$group:{"_id":{"sphere":"$sphere","region":"$region"},
                 "avg":{$avg:"$avg_salary"}}}
])
```